# Unable to take Credit Card payment via PayPal after civi update

Tags: civicontribute, paypal, user

Normally take credit card payments via civi with no problems - update to 5.10.0 and since then have been unable to take CC payment - error message staing 'Date Received is a required field.'

Process to replicate

Go to a contact (Member) -select payment tab - click Submit Credit Card Payment - Select Membership dues - enter amount - ignore Campaign - complete rest and click submit -error saying Date Received is a required field.

This happens whether send receipt is ticked or not and even though all dates are completed.

joomla 3.9.2 - Civicrm 5.10.0

Comment: Which payment processor are you using?

Answer (score 3):

@andygoodall thanks for posting this, we believe we have a fix for your issue, We are looking to conduct a point release for 5.10 to fix the issue however i would recommend if possible manually applying the change described in this [PR](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/13570)

Answer (score 2):

This is now fixed in 5.10.1...............